# using codebase element in .config file to load assembly from arbitrary path

Tags: .net, deployment

My problem is to try to figure out how to load a .NET assembly from an arbitrary location.  In my scenario, I don't want to use a subdirectory (ruling out a probing path approach) or the GAC.  The subdirectory approach causes multiple copies of the assembly to be stored, since multiple callers use the assembly.  The GAC scenario is the longer term answer, but there is some effort incurred in going to that approach.  For Visual Studio 2010 I see GAC usage as having these primary options: the built-in installer has received a lot of criticism, the InstallShield Limited edition is pretty sweet but doesn't appear to support GAC (paid InstallShield versions do, of course), and WiX is regarded as having a learning curve for use.

I mention all this about the GAC primarily because any of the numerous folks who have asked this question always seemed to get pointed in the direction of the GAC.  It is frustrating because the codebase element seems to be precisely what I desire for my strongly-named caller and called assemblies.
   My app.config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>

  <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/></startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft.com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="SharedProgramTest"
                          Culture="neutral"
                          PublicKeyToken="c422f85319da5fe0"
                          />
        <codeBase version ="1.0.0.1"
                  href="file:///D:/SomewhereElse/SharedProgramTest.dll" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Thanks, 
   John Wigger

Comment: What error do you get and what is the output of the fusion log?  http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/23/Assembly-probing_2C00_-Fusion-and-fuslogvw-in-5-minutes.aspx  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thottams/archive/2007/06/02/debugging-load-problems-using-fusion-log.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Does Assembly.LoadFile or Assembly.LoadFrom meet your requirements?

If not, I'm thinking you can hook into the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx

Comment: Although what you suggest would work with Assembly.LoadFile, it would be painful to remove a compile-time dependency in favor of a run-time dependency.  It would mean using reflection or perhaps dynamic language features, to access the classes in the assembly referred to.  My question was really focused around techniques that would give full compile-time type checking.

Comment: @John, please try my second suggestion, hooking into the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event to resolve the assembly during runtime.

Comment: I think your second suggestion gets into a similar chicken and egg sitution.  Based on the MSDN documentation it would let me allow me to deal with failed assembly resolution.However, the code I wrote will have failed since the AppDomain this code runs in would have already failed to load and aborted.I think your solutions do work,so I upvoted the answer,but think the effort to do so would result in bad code.I didn't accept the answer though,because it doesn't deal with a compile-time solution,explain that I misread the MSDN info on the codebase element,or confirm the MSDN info is wrong.